# Insert a New Line in Jquery tooltip plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Below is the css I am using for my jquery plugin.

> **CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body, div { font-family: arial, sans-serif;}
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    h3 {
        font-size: 110%;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: .2em 0 .5em 0;
    }
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3000;
        border: 1px solid #111;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #tooltip h3, #tooltip div { margin: 0; }
</style>
```

> **Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.studentclass').tooltip({ showURL: false, positionLeft: true, html:true});
        $("#block").click($.tooltip.block);
    });
</script>
```

> **HTML**

```
<label id="lblstudentname" 
    runat="server" 
    title="Name of the student in the class "
    class="studentclass">
        STUDENT
    </label>
```

I have tried using /br , /r/n , and pressing enter in the title but none of them seems to work. Can someone please help me .

Comment: **Which** jQuery tooltip plugin are you using?

Comment: Possible to link us up with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Missed adding in my question. Here is the link for the jquery plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: @Crowder, sure will do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) allows HTML in the tooltip. The HTML for a line break is `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery tipsy, which supports a `<br />`.

Or if you still want to use jquery tooltip, you can do it this way - [Multiple HTML lines with jquery tooltip plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490644/multiple-html-lines-with-jquery-tooltip-plugin?answertab=active#tab-top) which is a duplicate question/answer similar to what you want if you want full html support.

jquery tooltip should support `<br />` too.